# changing HTML characters with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page with javascript that hides and shows an element with a given ID (shown below). I would also like it to change a single character in the HTML text such that when the text is hidden a `»` character is shown and when the hidden text is made visible a `&#xFE3E` character is shown (same as the other character, but facing downwards)

What do I need to do to reference the element with the `pass »` and change it to `pass &#xFE3E`? Preferably, I would like to do this without knowing the first part of the text is `pass`. It could also be `fail`, for instance.

Thanks,
PaulH

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function toggle_visibility(id) 
        {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if(e.style.display == 'block')
            {
                e.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else
            {
                e.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('1');"><div class="bar"><span class="foo">pass »</span><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p></div></a>
    <div class="baz" id="1" style='display:none;'>
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sure someone will say it, but you could take the easy route and just use jQuery to do it in 2 lines. http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: I haven't heard of jquery before. Does it require that the PC viewing the page have an Internet connection to `jquery.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is basically what you asked for:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/C9KYM/

I added an `id` attribute to the span around `pass »` so it was easier to reference.

However, as others have stated, jQuery makes this easier.  But even without jQuery, you can simplify by adding spans for your open/close cases:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/4sBLU/

This removes the reliance on search/replace functionality, which may or may not work with special characters easily.  In addition, you could easily replace these spans with images.

Comment: The first one works wonderfully, except that the downward chevron looks like a ?. How do I get it to display that properly? If I replace the ? with &#xFE3E in the javascript it won't change back to the right-facing angle-bracket.

Comment: The browser or javscript converts &#xFE3E to the unicode character.  You can search replace on the character code like this:  `replace("\ufe3e", "»");` and this: `replace("»", "\ufe3e");`

Answer (score 1):

There are three main ways to do this.

#### Find and replace

You can [find and replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GGSkB/)):

```
function toggle_visibility(that, id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'block') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
        that.innerHTML = that.innerHTML.replace('\ufe3e', '\u00bb');
    }
    else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
        that.innerHTML = that.innerHTML.replace('\u00bb', '\ufe3e');
    }
}
```

`that` must point to the link to be changed:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility(this, '1');"> ...
```

Keep in mind that if there is an HTML tag inside `that` that must keep its expando properties or event handlers attached from within JavaScript, this method is not suitable.

#### Replace only a wrapped section

You would use something like:

```
<span class="foo">pass <span id="arrow" class="arrow">»</span></span>
```

And then change the HTML of the inner section only:

```
document.getElementById('arrow').innerHTML = '\ufe3e';
```

Keep in mind that duplicate IDs are invalid, so if you will have more than one of these collapse boxes on the page, a JavaScript library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) can help find the element by class instead:

```
var $arrow = $(that).find('.arrow');
$arrow.html($arrow.html().replace('\u00bb', '\ufe3e'));
```

#### Have CSS help you

You could use the CSS [`content` declaration](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html), but a more compatible (and possibly nicer looking) way to accomplish your task is to use background images ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eWgwL/8/)).

Here's how you would change the HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility(this, '1');"><div class="bar"><span class="foo arrowR">pass</span><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p></div></a>
```

You would use CSS like this:

```
.arrowD, .arrowR {
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 16px;
}
.arrowD {
    background-image: url('http://snap.lacounty.gov/Image/DownArrow.png');
}
.arrowR {
    background-image: url('http://snap.lacounty.gov/Image/RightArrow.png');
}
```

And change the class from JavaScript:

```
function toggle_visibility(that, id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id),
        f = that.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
    if (e.style.display == 'block') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
        f.className = f.className.replace('arrowD', '') + ' arrowR';
    }
    else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
        f.className = f.className.replace('arrowR', '') + ' arrowD';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap another span around the character you want to show. Then set the .innerHTML() of that span during your regular show/hide process.

You could also have both characters prewritten and just show/hide those spans as well.

If you need coded examples of this I can certainly help.